# Can MongoDB do alphanumeric sort?

Tags: mongodb

I need to do a alphanumeric sort on one of the fields in my collection. This field contains Chromosome info.

```
Chr1, 
Chr2,
..,
..,
..,
Chr10,
Chr11,
..,
..,
ChrX,
ChrY
```

Instead of getting the values in this order, I get them in

```
Chr1, 
Chr11
```

This is a common problem and was wondering whether MongoDB has an in-built solution for this sort or should we hack it as we normally do in Oracle. 
If there is no in-built solution, what is the best way to get this sort? Natural sort is an acceptable solution, but I have already applied it to another field.

Any help would would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's sorting as a string. There's no built-in way to handle this (is there in other DBs?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB has no build-in way of sorting data alphanumerical. But when all of your data has a field with a string with the same convention of "Chr" + number, you could put the number into a different field, keep it as an integer instead of a string, and sort by that.

Comment: Valid solution. Ask Tom website preaches the same.  I should have been more clear in my sample data. I also have some fields that can't be easily separated. ac1tg, ac2tg, 1actg etc. Any suggestions? I have a function in SQL Sever for sorting this field. Not sure about MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to "https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation".

Mongo provides collation for alphanumeric sorting.

Example:-

db.names.find({}).sort({username:1}).collation({locale:'en_US', numericOrdering:true})

Answer (score 0):

You can also use if you are using aggregation in mongodb:-

`db.names.aggregate([...query, {$sort:{username:1}]).collation({locale:'en_US', numericOrdering:true});`

Don't forget to add sorting of key in query array otherwise you will not get sorting order.

This thing is not available in documentation.